# How to implement one-to-one foreign key relation mapping in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to implement a *one-to-one* Hibernate relationship mapping, and I am new to Hibernate technology. My two entity classes are `Employee` and `Client`. Client should have a `employeeID` column as foreign key in database table; i.e. *this* client is handled by *this* employee.

Now there are two JSP pages through which I will submit the details of employee and client. First I will add/submit employee JSP. Then on client JSP page there would be a select box consisting `employeeID`s as its value.

I have done my JSP part. But I am doubtful of my one-to-one mapping relationship of client with employee. So I am providing my files of code.

Below is my code :

**employee class:**

```
public class RWEmp {
    private int id; 
    private String strName;
    private String strContactNum;
    private String strDateOfJoining;
    private String strDesignation;
    public RWEmp(){
    }
    // getter/setters
}
```

**client class:**

```
public class RWClient {
    private int id;
    private String strName;
    private RWEmp poc_emp;  // point of contact employee as employee object
    public RWClient(){
    }
    // getter/setters
}
```

employee.hbm.xml is straight forward. i.e. no relationship.
But client is having a `has a` relation with employee object.

**client.hbm.xml:**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.rightwave.entities.RWClient" table="client_master">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="strName" type="string" column="cl_name" />
        <many-to-one name="poc_emp" class="com.rightwave.entities.RWEmp" column="poc_emp" unique="true"></many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**persisting class:**

```
public class PersistEntities {

    public void clientPersist() {
        Session session=Factory.getSession();
        Transaction tr=session.beginTransaction();
        
        RWEmp rwEmp =new RWEmp();
        rwEmp.setId(2); // this will come from jsp page <select> value. I am doubtful of this, explained below in question.
        
        RWClient rwClient1=new RWClient("wso2",rwEmp);
        
        session.save(rwClient1);
        session.flush();
        tr.commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Here I am not sure if this blueprint is right or wrong. Can I set the `employeeID`, which will come from my client jsp page (from in `<select>` box). I am confused because here I am only setting `employeeID`, which has to be already existing to be a valid foreign key of client. But there are no checks of validating whether this `employeeID` is already existing or not. The `Employee` object will definitely be saved (from `employee.jsp`) before client object.

Am I doing it right way?

Comment: I believe you are able to save the `rwClient1` with your current code. But then what if the `rwEmp` with id 2 gets deleted from some other action (jsp)after your jsp got displayed but before saving the `rwClient1`. Is this the scenario you are asking about? And why do you have `unique="true"` for `many-to-one`, since one employee id can be assigned to multiple clients?

Comment: yes, it is getting saved. Yes I am also having the same concern you mentioned here about what will happen if empID 2 gets deleted before saving rwClient1. I was told by someone that `unique=true` makes a relation one to one. I need : one employee ID can be assigned to only one client.

Comment: what is the best approach here?

Comment: That is a valid concern. I think it fits in [long conversation pattern](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-basics-apptx). Regarding employees unique, I think that does not fit your need. Please check.

Comment: is there any other alternate mapping, that I can use instead of `<many-to-one unique="true">` Because I require one team lead (i.e. employee) to be a point of contact person for one client.

Comment: you can try removing the `unique=true`. But my intent is, if you are using this domain model to generate the schema by hibernate automatically, it will result in creating unique constraint on this column which doesn't allow one employee to be assigned to only one client. I presume you wanted to associate on employee to multiple client. if not, you are good with `unique=true`.

Answer (score 0):

When establishing one-to-one relationship with two entities both are assigned the same primary key. A special foreign identifier generator should be declared on `Client` table to get the primary key value from `Employee` table. Add `constrained="true"` to ensure the `Employee` exists.

```xml
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.rightwave.entities.RWClient" table="client_master">        
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="foreign">
                <param name="property">poc_emp</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <one-to-one name="poc_emp" class="com.rightwave.entities.RWEmp"
            constrained="true"></one-to-one>
        <property name="strName" type="string" column="cl_name" />        
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```